# htaccess restrict access to files in directory in WordPress without cookie set

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm really struggling to get this to work. I've cobbled together bits and pieces from all over the place and finally seem to have the redirect working, however, it seems to ignore the cookie check and just redirects whether the cookie is set or not.

I'm also struggling to find a resource that explains what all the htaccess variables mean. I've found plenty of places where they're listed. I can't even find an explanation for %{REQUEST_URI}, I'm assuming it means the domain.

I am to trying to redirect anyone trying to access any files in a specific directory to a login page unless they have a cookie set.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-content/uploads/my/directory/.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !my-cookie-name=1
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}/client-login/ [L]
```

Comment: So you want to block access to all files in `/wp-content/uploads/my/directory/` directory when cookie is not set?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this rule in `/wp-content/uploads/my/directory/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !my-cookie-name=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /client-login/ [L,R]
```

For this rule to be used in root .htaccess:

**Make sure to place it at top of your .htaccess.**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /wp-content/uploads/my/directory/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !my-cookie-name=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /client-login/ [L,R]

# rest of your rules go below this
```

Comment: Thanks, I am doing this for multiple domains, so I'd really like to do it in the root directory if possible.

Comment: This will work for multiple domains as long as restricted directory is `/wp-content/uploads/my/directory/`

Comment: Good point, but I do want one place to manage all the rules really. The directory could be different on every site, so I don't want to keep looking for the folder, I'd rather just type in the url.